# Static interface equivalent C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, static

I've worked with singletons in the past and I'm aware it's a solution for some people who are trying solve the static interface problem. In my case, I can't really use a singleton because I have an external class that I'm inheriting from and I have no control over this one (a library).

Basically, I have many classes inheriting from "TableRow" (the class in the library) and I need every single of these classes to implement a certain static method (ex: GetStaticIdentifier). Eventually, I need to store these objects in one of their base types, and use the static method on this specific type.

My question, is there another solution to this than using a singleton? Is there a feature I'm not aware of in C# that would help me solve this problem?

Comment: "I need every single of these classes to implement a certain static method"  Why? What's the use case?  Shouldn't the classes be responsible for their own implementation detail?

Comment: Why can't you just call on single static method? Or you need unique static method with given name per type?

Comment: Yes @AlexeiLevenkov, I need to have different implementations on each class, the method returns an object of the base type, but it should be of the type where the static method is implemented...

Comment: If you have objects of this classes why you need static method, why not just declare non-static virtual method and override them in child classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to supply some meta-information along with the subclasses of `TableRow`; meta-information that can be retrieved *without instantiating the particular subclass*.

While .NET lacks static interfaces and static polymorphism, this can (to some extent, see below) be solved with [custom attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In other words, you can define a custom attribute class that stores the information you want to associate with your type:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class StaticIdentifierAttribute : Attribute
{
    public StaticIdentifierAttribute(int id)
    {
        this.staticIdentifier = id;
    }

    private readonly int staticIdentifier;

    public int StaticIdentifier {
        get {
            return staticIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then apply this custom attribute to your `TableRow` subclasses:

```
[StaticIdentifier(42)]
public class MyTableRow : TableRow
{
    // ...
}
```

You can then retrieve the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance for `MyTableRow` (or any other subclass of `TableRow`) and use the [`GetCustomAttributes` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the `StaticIdentifierAttribute instance and read out the value stored in its`StaticIdentifier` property for the class.

The **drawback** compared to static interfaces and static polymorphism is that it is not compile-time ensured that each `TableRow` subclass actually has that attribute; you will have to catch that (and either throw an exception, or ignore the respective `TableRow` subclass) at runtime.

Moreover, you cannot ensure that the attribute is *only* applied to `TableRow` subclasses, but then, while this may be a bit untidy, it doesn't really matter (if it is applied to another class, it will just not have any effect there, as no code ever processes it for other classes).

Answer (score 0):

If you twist yourself in knots, you can get a small amount of compiler checking. However, declaring a new struct type for every identifier instance you want is admittedly insane.

```
public interface IIdentifier
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class BaseClass { }

public class ClassWithId<T> : BaseClass where T :  IIdentifier, new()
{
    public static int Id { get { return (new T()).Id; } }
}

public struct StaticId1 : IIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get { return 1; } }
}

public struct StaticId2 : IIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get { return 2; } }
}

//Testing
Console.WriteLine(ClassWithId<StaticId1>.Id);   //outputs 1
Console.WriteLine(ClassWithId<StaticId2>.Id);   //outputs 2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using static class with generic(or not) extension methods ?

```
public static class Helper
{
  fields...

  public static void DoSomething<T>(this T obj)
  {
     do something...
  }
}
```